# Изменение значений переменных java

Tags: java

Как можно изменить значение переменной класса из окружающего кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное предполагается не класс а экземпляр класса.и переменная не статическая.

Пусть будет класс;

```
class Thing {
    public int variable;
}
```

И у нас есть его экземпляр

```
Thing thing = new Thing();
```

Если переменная имеет модификатор `public` или `package private`(без указания модификатора доступа) то изменение её значения тривиально и выглядит как

```
thing.variable = 1;
```

ps: `package private` поля доступны **внутри пакета**

Если же переменная имеет модификатор доступа `private`, то вариантов 2

1. Определение метода-мутатора, кторый изменяет значение переменной, в соответствии с внутренней логикой класса

   ```
   void updateValue() {
      variable ++;
   }
   ```

При этом для изменения значения надо в управляющем коде вызвать этот метод:

```
 thing.updateValue();
```

2. Reflection API:

   ```
   final Field field = Thing.class.getDeclaredField("variable");
   field.setAccessible(true); // получение доступа к private полю
   final Object oldValue = field.get(Thing.class);
   field.set(oldValue, newValue);
   ```

Последний способ будет медленнее, чем доступ через метод или напрямую.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала создать объект этого класса, если это возможно.

Это можно сделать с помощью прямого доступа к переменной, хотя это не желательно

Например:

```
m.a = 5;
```

С помощью сеттеров и геттеров получить и изменить значение переменной класса.(Предпочтительнее)

Например:

```
m.setValueA(5);
```

Или

```
m.getValueA();
```

Или с помощью рефлексии.

Если есть код, скиньте

Answer (score 0):

Для этого надо создать экземпляр класса. Например это можно сделать с помощью оператора `new`.

После этого можно использовать ссылку на объект, для доступа к переменной, и если она недоступна извне то использовать мутаторы переменной, то есть методы которые меняют значение переменной.